# Cycle-type (group-theory)

Tags: group-theory

**Is there a formula for $\#$cycle types in $S_n$?**

> **Example:** *all cyle-types for $S_5$:*
>   \begin{align}
> &(5)\\
> &(41)\\
> &(32)\\
> &(311)\\
> &(221)\\
> &(2111)\\
> &(11111)\\
> \end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of cycle types of $S_n$ is the number of ways to "partition" $n$, and there is no nice formula for this. See this wikipedia page for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Answer (score 3):

There is one cycle type in $S_n$ for each [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of $n$. Unfortunately, there is no nice, simple formula for the partition function.